# Can I build a Docker container from the CLI against a remote daemon?

Tags: windows, docker, virtualization

Currently I've the following setup:

- An Hyper-V VM running Windows 10 on which is my dev machine. My CPU doesn't support *nested virtualization*.
- *Docker for Windows* is installed on the host machine which runs Windows 10 too.

Is it possible to run `docker build` from the VM against Docker on the host machine?

Comment: Yes, just use PowerShell from the guest to run `docker build` on the host.

Comment: @ΔλЛ So I need to enable remote Powershell commands from the host, right?

Comment: Either that or just open a PowerShell session from guest to host.

Comment: @ΔλЛ Ok I could configure my host to accept remote PowerShell sessions. So... now I understand that I should copy the sources to the remote host via the remote PowerShell session and then run `docker build .`?

Comment: You didn't mention having sources on the guest but if that's the case then yes, copy them and run `docker build` using PowerShell.

Comment: @ΔλЛ Well, sources should be in the VM as it's the *dev machine* :D

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/), there is 3 ways to do this,

```
# with Git repo
docker -H xxx build https://github.com/docker/rootfs.git#container:docker

# Tarball contexts
docker -H xxx build http://server/context.tar.gz

Text files
docker -H xxx build - < Dockerfile
```

When doing this, you need to make sure that,

1. your client have docker installed.
2. all the dependent files are accessible by the host.

At the end, the docker image will be created in your host.

---

### Update

the docker options is documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/) now.

Comment: The questions is about build on a remote docker daemon, not about building locally remote files.

Comment: hi @motobói, please read carefully. it is `docker` with argument `-H xxx`, specifying the remote host. using remote files is one of the easiest way to make sure remote host has access to all depending files.

Comment: The documentation you linked does not mention an `-H` option now. Has it been removed/renamed?

Comment: You should consider highlighting the ```-H``` option, it is not that obvious for someone who doesn't know the docker cli

Answer (score 2):

```
export DOCKER_HOST=ssh://sammy@your_server_ip
```

then you can run `docker build` on your host machine

[reference](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-a-remote-docker-server-to-speed-up-your-workflow)

Answer (score 0):

There is (from my understanding) 3 different way of building a docker using a remote docker host / daemon:

1. Using the `DOCKER_HOST` variable
2. Using `contexts`
3. Using `-H` cli option

as in :

1. `DOCKER_HOST="ssh://user@docker-build.dev" docker build -t toto .`
2. `docker use context remote-build-host && docker build -t toto .`
3. `docker -H ssh://user@docker-build.dev:22 build -t toto .`

Please note the port is required in the last form (`-H`)

See [this page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/) and [this one](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/docker/) too for more info.